# Finding the density function of U=XY where X ,Y are independent random variables with known density functions.

Tags: calculus, statistics, probability-distributions

Assume X has the desity function given by

$ f_X(x) = 1/(π\sqrt{1-x^2})$ if  $-1 \lt x \lt 1$ and $0$ if $|x| \ge 1$.

If an independent random variable Y has density

$f_Y(y) = ye^{-y^2/2}$ if $y \ge 0$ and $0$ if $y \lt 0$.

find a density function U=XY.

My attempt:

Since X and Y are independent their joint density can be given from $f(x,y) =f_Xf_Y=ye^{-y^2/2}/(π\sqrt{1-x^2})$ for $-1 \lt x \lt 1$ and $y \gt 0$ and $0$ otherwise.
Consider the one to one mapping of the xy-plane onto the uv-plane $
u=xy$  and $v=y $
and let the inverse mapping be given by $x=Q(u,v)=u/v$ and $y=R(u,v)=v$ for $v \gt 0$.
In the uv-plane a density g of (U,V) is given by $g(u,v)=f[Q(u,v),R(u,v)] \vert \partial(Q,R)/{ \partial(u,v)} \vert = \frac {e^{-v^2/2}}{π \sqrt{1-(u/v)^2}}$.
The density $f_U$ can be obtained by

$f_U = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(u,v) dv = \int_{|u|}^{\infty} \frac {e^{-v^2/2}}{π \sqrt{1-(u/v)^2}}dv = \frac{e^{-u^2/2}}{\sqrt{2π}}$.

I am wondering if my thinking is right in general and if the calculation of the last integral is correct.

If I am wrong I would like to know  why and a correct way to approach the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: $|x|<1, y>0 \implies |u|<v$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!So the integral from 0 to infinity is the density of U=XY?

Comment: No, $v$ clearly depends on $u$.

Comment: Ok!Really grateful!